# Looking up values from one dataframe in specific row of another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I'm struggling with a bit of a complex (to me) lookup-type problem.

I have a dataframe df1 that looks like this:

```
    Grade  Value
0     A     16
1     B     12
2     C      5
```

And another dataframe (df2) where the values in one of the columns('Grade') from df1 forms the index:

```
     Tier 1  Tier 2  Tier 3
A      20      17      10
B      16      11       3
C       7       6       2
```

I've been trying to write a bit of code that for each row in df1, look ups the row corresponding with 'Grade' in df2, finds the smallest value in df2 greater than 'Value', and returns the name of that column.

E.g. for the second row of df1, it looks up the row with index 'B' in df2: 16 is the smallest value greater than 12, so it returns 'Tier 1'. Ideal output would be:

```
    Grade  Value  Tier
0     A     16    Tier 2 
1     B     12    Tier 1
2     C      5    Tier 2
```

My novice, downloaded-Python-last-week attempt so far has been as follows, which is throwing up all manner of errors and doesn't even try returning the column name. Sorry also about the micro-ness of the question: any help appreciated!

```
for i, row in input_df1.iterrows():
    Tier = np.argmin(df1['Value']<df2.loc[row,0:df2.shape[1]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2.loc[df1.Grade].eq(df1.Value, 0).idxmax(1)
```